# c++ : comparison function for next_permutation

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, std

I want to use `std::next_permutation()` on a vector of Object.

To do so I have to define a comparison function that defines the `< operator` between two Objects (otherwise it will take a default comparison operator that has an unpredictable behavior)

But sometimes I got two Objects that are equal (according to my criteria) and so `Object1 < Object2` and `Object2 < Object1` both return `false` so next_permutation() turns indefinitely...

**EDIT** : here is a simple example of what I have (the loop never ends)

**MyObject.h :**

```
class MyObject {
    int param;
    MyObject(int i);

};
```

**Main.cpp :**

```
bool comparison (MyObject * o1, MyObject * o2) { return (o1->param < o2->param); }

int main(){

    std::vector<MyObject*> myVector;
    myVector.push_back(new MyObject(0));
    myVector.push_back(new MyObject(1));
    myVector.push_back(new MyObject(1));

    std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), comparison);

    do{
        printf("%i, %i, %i \n", myVector[0]->param, myVector[1]->param, myVector[2]->param);
    } while(std::next_permutation(myVector.begin(), myVector.end()), comparison);

    return 0;
}
```

So how could I handle that case ? How does the default `< operator` handles this case ?

Comment: That should work just fine. Does this actually run indefinitely? It shouldn’t.

Comment: You may have *equivalent* elements with `std::next_permutation()`.

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Where does it stay indefinitely?

Comment: it actually runs indefinitely. Let me add some code that could reproduce my problem.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: How did you prove that it runs "indefinitely"? When did you stop waiting for it to be "indefinite"?

Comment: `next_permutation` will halt when it doesn't find a pair of elements in order `i,j` such that `i<j`. If you have two objects for which `a<b` returns false in both directions, `next_permutation` would return false right off the back...

Comment: This may not be the reason for your issue. If you sort the `vector` before execute `std::next_permutation` you may be able to reduce a few iterations

Comment: Works [here](https://ideone.com/LqkJrA).

Comment: well this is amazing ! It does not on my visual studio 2012... Could that be a configuration problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```
while(std::next_permutation(myVector.begin(), myVector.end()), comparison)
```

your parent is misplaced

it should be

```
while(std::next_permutation(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), comparison))
```

else you do `std::next_permutation` with default comparison, discard result with comma operator and then return `comparison` which is always true (function pointer not null)

Comment: This is brilliant ! I have been wondering so long about that comparison operator, while the problem was a syntax one !
Thanks for the explanation also.

Answer (score -1):

> But sometimes I got two Objects that are equal

`std::next_permutation` does not require a range of unique elements.

Therefore, this should work. **You did something wrong.**

> So how could I handle that case ?

Fix your bug.

Of course, we have no way of knowing what that is, as you failed to present [your testcase](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).